# url_for created a wrong path to static folder

Tags: python, flask

We have a Flask app running on our server (xxxx.edu.au:5000). However, we set a proxy up `xxxx.edu.au/getseq` which forwards the request to `xxxx.edu.au:5000`

Unfortunately, in the browser, now we get `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://xxxx.edu.au/static/vehicle.js”`.

This is the flask app structure:

```
flask
├── getseq.py
├── static
│   └── vehicle.js
└── templates
    └── example.html
```

The flask app written here:

```
$ cat getseq.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from wtforms import Form, RadioField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.widgets import TextArea

SECRET_KEY = 'development'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
...

@app.route("/getseq/<mrna_id>", methods=['post', 'get'])    
def get_sequences(mrna_id):
    ...
    return render_template('example.html', form=form)

@app.route("/getseq/health", methods=['get'])
def health():
    response = app.response_class(
        status=200,
        mimetype='text/html'
    )
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("starting...")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

The path `vehicle.js` get defined here:

```
$ cat templates/example.html 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='vehicle.js')}}"></script>
...
```

How is it possible to change `url_for` or do I have to change `getseq.py`?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Where is the view handler code that renders `templates/example.html`?

Comment: It gets renders in `get_sequences(mrna_id)` as `return render_template('example.html', form=form)`. This html file which is in a template folder gets displayed in the browser correctly. I updated my question.

Comment: Does `https://xxxx.edu.au/getseq/static/vehicle.js` work?

Comment: No, it doesn't and I got `Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again`

Comment: How did you setup your proxy?

Comment: It runs on AWS. What specif information would you need?

Comment: Is it just the `/getseq` endpoint of `xxxx.edu.au/getseq` that proxies to `xxxx.edu.au:5000`? It sounds like that may be the case and would explain why `/static` doesn't resolve. If that's the case, my answer below should work for you. Or can you proxy `xxxx.edu.au` to `xxxx.edu.au:5000`?

Comment: Yes, `/getseq` is the endpoint of `xxxx.edu.au/getseq`. No, I can't proxy `xxxx.edu.au` to `xxxx.edu.au:5000`.

Answer (score 0):

Without duplicating your issue it's hard to tell what is causing your static asset to fail. As a workaround you could read `vehicle.js` on the server, base64 encode it, pass it into your template context, and render the script tag with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data:text/javascript;base64,{{ base64_encoded_data }}"></script>
```

**EDIT**
In your view handler:

```
import base64


@app.route("/getseq/<mrna_id>", methods=['post', 'get'])    
def get_sequences(mrna_id):
    with open('static/vehicle.js', 'rb') as f:
        base64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    return render_template('example.html', form=form, base64_encoded_data=base64_encoded_data)
```

Comment: How should I change `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='vehicle.js')}}"></script>` in `template/example.html `?

Comment: You shouldn't need to concern yourself with jquery CDN, just the `url_for` to your static asset. See my edit for passing the `base64_encoded_data` into the template context